# Flutter Dismissible undo animation using AnimatedList

Tags: dart, flutter

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ++flag;
    return AnimatedList(
      key: Key(flag.toString()),
      initialItemCount: numbers.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key(numbers[index].toString()),
          background: Container(color: Colors.green),
          child: ListTile(title: Text("Item = ${numbers[index].toString()}")),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            setState(() => numbers.removeAt(index));
            Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () => setState(() => numbers.insert(index, index)));
          },
        );
      },
    );
}
```

For simplicity I am using `Timer` to add the deleted number after 1500 ms. Everything works great but I can't see the animation when the list is updated (after 1500 ms), how can I make use of `animation` parameter to animate the list?

Screenshot:
[image]

---

**TL;DR: How can I have animation when the item is put back in the `AnimatedList`?**

Comment: you are basically not using the last parameter passed to `itemBuilder`, also i cannot understand what you need that `Timer` for...

Comment: @pskink Timer is just used to insert the value back to the list, it doesn't do anything else. I want to have the animation when the item is added back to the list, don't know where to use `animation`

Comment: honestly i dont get it: you use `Dismissible` to insert a new item?

Comment: @pskink, actually when you see apps like Gmail which allow you to undo a deletion of a conversation, so it adds the item back to the list. I was looking for something like that.

Comment: so doesn't `AnimatedListState#insertItem` work?

Comment: I don't know how to use that. Can you post the code, I will be happy to accept and upvote your answer.

Comment: it takes int position and animation  `Duration` - position is where you want your item to be inserted in the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
List<int> _list = List.generate(5, (i) => i);
GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _key = GlobalKey();
int _index;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: _myWidget(),
    appBar: AppBar(
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.undo),
          onPressed: () {
            _list.insert(_index, _index);
            _key.currentState.insertItem(_index);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget _myWidget() {
  return AnimatedList(
    key: _key,
    initialItemCount: _list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
      return Dismissible(
        key: Key("${_list[index]}"),
        child: SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: animation,
          child: ListTile(title: Text("Item = ${_list[index]}")),
        ),
        background: Container(color: Colors.green),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          setState(() {
            _index = index;
            _list.removeAt(index);
            _key.currentState.removeItem(index, (_, __) => Container());
          });
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert items using `AnimatedList`, you need to call the method `AnimatedListState.insertItem(int index)`

```
AnimatedList.of(context).insertItem(0);
```

You can also obtain the `AnimatedListState` using a `GlobalKey`

```
final foo = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AnimatedList(
    key: foo,
    // ...
  );
}

  // elsewhere
foo.currentState.insertItem(0);
```

Comment: I tried but my code is breaking, the key used in `AnimatedList` and `Dismissible` are something making the code break. Can you please write the complete working code (using my posted code)?